# Why is $F(N_t \times (a_t , b_t))$ is contained in an evenly covered neighborhood of $F(y_0, t)$ in Theorem 1.7 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology?

Tags: algebraic-topology

The Proof of Theorem 1.7 of Hatcher's Algebraic Topology says, "Since F is continuous, every point $(y_0, t) \in Y \times I$ has a product neighborhood $N_t \times (a_t, b_t)$ such that $F(N_t \times (a_t , b_t))$ is contained in an evenly covered neighborhood of $F(y_0, t)$."

F being continuous implies $F(N_t \times (a_t , b_t))$ is contained in some neighborhood of $F(y_0, t)$.

Why is $F(N_t \times (a_t , b_t))$ contained in an **evenly covered** neighborhood of $F(y_0, t)$?

Answer (score 0):

$F(y_0,t)$ has an evenly covered open neighborhood $U$. Thus $F^{-1}(U)$ is an open neighborhood of $(y_0,t)$. It contains a product neighborhood as in your question (recall the definition of the product topology).